# Order of 301 Redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am curious if someone could educate me to better understand why the following does not work based on the order.

When I have the redirect for /contact first the location pages fail to redirect properly.

```
Redirect 301 /contact http://www.example.com/contact-us

Redirect 301 /index.php/contact/location1 http://www.example.com/contact-us/location1

Redirect 301 /index.php/contact/location2 http://www.example.com/contact-us/location1
```

When I have it after the locations, they work normally. Why is this?

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/contact/location1 http://www.example.com/contact-us/location1

Redirect 301 /index.php/contact/location2 http://www.example.com/contact-us/location1

Redirect 301 /contact http://www.example.com/contact-us
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because other 2 URLs also have `/contact` in them.

It is always better to use `RedirectMatch`directive that with capability to use regex so that you can match exactly what you need.

Using `RedirectMatch`directive following will also work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact/?$ http://www.example.com/contact-us

RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/contact/location1/?$ http://www.example.com/contact-us/location1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/contact/location2/?$ http://www.example.com/contact-us/location1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes perfect sense now!